# Rails 3 flexible CMS framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are some other similar questions here but they're fairly old when Rails 3 was still in beta.

I am looking for a CMS system for Rails 3. I need something with basic functionality (pages, SEO etc.) and good/easy extensibility. The most important feature other than extensibility that I want is a good WYSIWYG editor. I will be using it to build CMSs for clients and need something flexible that I can extend easily to fit their needs. Since HTML will be prepared by someone else, I need the option to use html.erb format or something similar.

Some that I've seen:
- Refinery CMS
- Radiant CMS (is this rails 3 compatible? not sure...)
- Typus
- BrowserCMS

So, what do you guys recommend and why?

Comment: Try Radiant (http://radiantcms.org/). I've used it briefly for something I needed to setup in a few minutes and it did what I needed it to do and was fairly easy to use.

Comment: Except not compatible with Rails 3..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is supported with [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com/). Pages and SEO support is out of the box and you can easily extend it with [Rails::Engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), where you are using same development workflow as in standard Rails3 application. There is also a CRUD engine generator, sou you can build your extensions very fast.

Your views are under app/views or vendor/engines/name/app/views and you can use erb for it.

You can start with reading [guides](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-refinery). If you need help, you can join  #refinerycms at Freenode [irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/) servers or ask in [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms?pli=1).

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly new one that I believe is being actively worked on.

Locomotive

http://www.locomotivecms.com/

Comment: Locomotive looks really promising. Editing the templates is a pain though.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I tried all these, but I'm not too impressed with any:

- Refinery CMS: could not set it up, bug, did workaround, new bug. maybe just unfortunate timing, but bad impression. will keep trying though
- Radiant CMS: bugged out, maybe not rails 3 compatible. could not try it.
- Typus: worked fine, but it's not so much as CMS as it is a admin interface... in this case i'm looking for a more full blown solution, but seems like a nice project, might use it for other stuff.
- BrowserCMS: bug on generator. could not get it to work.

Kinda frustrating and disappointing, I wasn't expecting such problems with "big" rails projects. Obviously someone didn't do their tests right ^_^

Comment: I suspect there is a larger problem here (on your end), at least I don't currently have any problems with refinery or radiant locally.  I did have issues with refinery a few weeks ago, I think it was due to an out-of-date version being up on rubygems, but at the moment I don't have any problems starting up a ruby-1.9.2 RVM setup with refinery (0.9.9.13).